# Pinescript: Detect when any part of a candle touches a given range

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a range which prints as a cloud on the chart, which has the low defined as series float:

```
sensitiveCloudBottom
```

as the high as series float:

```
sensitiveCloudTop
```

I want to detect whether any part of the candle touches this range. I've set a bool as

```
withinCloud = (close>sensitiveCloudBottom and close<sensitiveCloudTop)
```

which works on 90% of cases, but if the candle shoots straight through the cloud, or moves in and out in the same candle, the bool changes to false again.

I've tried logic like

```
withinCloud = (close>sensitiveCloudBottom and close<sensitiveCloudTop) or (low<sensitiveCloudBottom and high>sensitiveCloudTop) or (high>sensitiveCloudBottom and high<sensitiveCloudTop) or (low>sensitiveCloudBottom and low<sensitiveCloudTop)
```

but I'm worried I might have missed a potential touching candle. Surely there's a simpler way of doing this, isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
withinCloud = high >= sensitiveCloudBottom and low <= sensitiveCloudTop
```

Comment: Haha. So simple! Gutted I missed that. Thanks so much for your help.